# RFM69HCW connected to Arduino Nano 33 BLE

Tags: arduino-nano-ble, lora

I tried to connect my RFM69HCW to Arduino Nano 33 BLE, so that I won't be needing a logic level shifter to downgrade the voltage, since Arduino Nano is already 3.3V. Upon checking its data sheet and pinout, I noticed there's no dedicated pin for CS (Chip Select).

Which pin should I use as CS in the Arduino Nano?

Which pin should I connect the DI0 pin of RFM69HCW in the Arduino Nano?

Answer (score 0):

On any Arduino you can use any free digital pin as SPI CS.

Comment: Okay. Thank you! Even the DI0 pin of RFM69HCW can I connect it too to any pins of Arduino Nano?

Comment: @lostresearch, why not? it is free. the SPI pins on Nano are 11, 12 and 13

Answer (score 0):

There is no dedicated CS pin, and you can use any available Dx pin – which enables you, among other things, to have several devices on the same bus. The CS pin allows you to select (hence the S) the right device.